# How difficult is it to find the "pre-image" of a block cipher?

Tags: aes, block-cipher, preimage-resistance

Say that I have

$$ C_1 = AES_{k_1}(M_1) $$

How difficult would it be to find a key, K<sub>2</sub> and plaintext M<sub>2</sub>

$$ C_2 = AES_{k_2}(M_2) $$

such that

$$ C_1 == C_2 $$

How would using a block cipher algorithm other than AES effect this problem?

Comment: Pick any key $k_2$ and decrypt $C_1$ to obtain $M_2$.

Comment: @Thomas I guess I'm asking is there a way to do this without enumerating the entire key space...

Comment: Or better yet, what about the scenario where $M_1$ and $M_2$ are fixed.

Comment: @samoz If $M_2$ isn't fixed then Thomas' suggestion works for *every* key.

Comment: Some precisions about your question would be useful. 1. As written, the natural interpretation is to consider that $M_1$ is a single-block message. It is really what you intended ? 2. When you say a plaintext $M_2$, people here understand that $M_2$ can be an arbitrary binary string of the right length. Did you intend to say a _meaningful_ message ? If so, you need to add a description of what is acceptable.

Answer (score 8):

Take $C_2$ and pick **any** $k_2$. Then decrypt using $k_2$ so that $M_2 = AES_{k_2}^{-1}(C_2)$. Now obviously we have $AES_{k_2}(M_2) = C_2 = C_1$.

This extends to any blockcipher, because blockciphers are specifically designed to be reversible.

---

In the comments you asked about the scenario where $M_2$ is also fixed. This is as hard as breaking AES. Consider this problem:

Find $k_2$ given $k_1, M_1, M_2$ such that:

$$AES_{k_1}(M_1) = AES_{k_2}(M_2)$$

Giving $k_1$ (and thereby $M_1$) does not add information for the solver to this problem, because there is no relation between $k_1$ and $k_2$ other than that there exists a ciphertext that was created using both keys - which is non-information because all keys can create such ciphertext given the correct plaintext. Thus the problem with irrelevant information removed becomes:

Find $k_2$ given $M_2$ such that:

$$C_2 = AES_{k_2}(M_2)$$

This is obviously the problem of breaking AES itself.